# How to see the stdout of a child process?

Tags: operating-system

So I am doing some system programming in C. I encountered a problem.

I fork() a child process, and then use pipe() to send a message from the parent to the child. And the child does receive the incoming message from pipe. What I want to do is printing out this message to the child's screen. But write(stdout, message, xxx) will not work because it would print the message to parent's screen.

So I am wondering what is needed to be done in order to print the message to child's screen.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to get the child to write to its own STDOUT.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use write(stdout.....

Try something like below: print the message received from pipe in "ChildProcess" function

```
void  main(void)
{
     pid_t  pid;

     pid = fork();
     if (pid == 0) 
          ChildProcess();
     else 
          ParentProcess();
}

void  ChildProcess(void)
{
     int   i;


     printf("   *** Message recieved from parent pipe ***\n");
}
```

This is concept behind it. When the main program executes fork(), an identical copy of its address space, including the program and all data, is created. System call fork() returns the child process ID to the parent and returns 0 to the child process.